# What is the inverse image of the open disk $D_{1/2}(0) $ under the complex function $f(z)= \frac{z}{z+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

> What is the inverse image of the open disk $D_{1/2}(0) = \{z\; \big| \;
> |z| < \frac12\} $ under the complex function $f(z)= \frac{z}{z+1} ?$

Let $z \in \mathbb{C} $ lie in the inverse image of this open disk, then we must have

$$|\frac{z}{z+1}|  < \frac12 \rightarrow 2|z| < |z+1| \rightarrow 2|z| < |z| + 1 \rightarrow |z| < 1$$

Hence, the  open disk $D_1(0) $ is contained in the inverse image. How do I find the actual inverse image?

Comment: The inverse of the Möbius transformation $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is $f^{-1}(z) = \frac{dz-b}{-cz+a}$ (by direct calculation or the representation by $2\times2$ matrices). Therefore you seek the image of $D_{1/2}(0)$ under the map $f^{-1}(z) = \frac{z}{-z+1}$. By the way, your argument correctly shows that the answer is contained in $D_1(0)$ (not the other way around).

Comment: Do you know the theory about general Möbius transforms? That can be fruitfully applied here...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma and Greg Martin I don't know that theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\frac z{z+1}=w\iff1-\frac1{z+1}=w\iff z=-1+\frac1{1-w}.$$Therefore, $f^{-1}\bigl(D_{1/2}(0)\bigr)$ is $g\bigl(D_{1/2}(0)\bigr)$, with$$g(w)=-1+\frac1{1-w}.$$So, you can solve your problem in three steps:

1. The map $w\mapsto 1-w$ maps $D_{1/2}(0)$ onto $D_{1/2}(1)$.
2. The inversion maps $D_{1/2}(1)$ onto $D_{2/3}\left(\frac43\right)$.
3. Finally, the map $w\mapsto w-1$ maps $D_{2/3}\left(\frac43\right)$ onto $D_{2/3}\left(\frac13\right)$.

Comment: am unable to understand how the inversion map is working on that open disk, is there a theory related to this that I can read? Could you give me some keyword to search for?  Also am getting $z= \frac{1}{1-w} -1$

Comment: Yes, you are right about the anaytical expression for $f^{-1}$ (I've edited my answer). On the other hand, use the fact that the inversion maps circles (not passing through the origin) into circles and closed disks (to which the origin does not belong) into closed disks. And so you only have to compute the inversion of the circle centered at $1$ with radius $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's bijective, and the inverse is  $\dfrac w{1-w}$.  Let's look at what happens to boundary of the region.  Remember, generalized circles go to generalized circles.  We have $1/2\mapsto1, -1/2\mapsto-1/3$ and $i/2\mapsto(2i-1)/5$.

Thus the boundary circle goes to the circle determined by $1,-1/3$ and $(2i-1)/5$.

Now, as a test point, $0\mapsto0$.

So, we get that the interior of  the disc maps to the disc $D(1/3,2/3)$.